# Can't get params from any HTTP request in php

Tags: php, rest

I can't get request params from php//input, it's always returning empty string.
$_POST is also always empty, the only way I could get params is using $_REQUEST, and I'm not sure if it's right way to solve this problem.

```
var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

returns: string(0) ""

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

returns: array(0) { }

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

returns: array(2) {
  ["ergerg"]=>
  string(6) "ergerg"
  ["regergerg"]=>
  string(6) "ergreg"
}

My request in Postman looks like :

```
POST  /api/ajax.php?ergerg=ergerg&regergerg=ergreg

response
Status:200 OK
Time:192 ms
Size:236 B
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$obj = json_decode($rest_json);
$request = $obj->request;

if($request == 1){
    $userData = mysqli_query($con, "select * from rows");

    $response = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userData)) {
        $response[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}

if($request == 2){
    $platform   = $data->platform;
    $container1 = $data->container1;
    $container2 = $data->container2;
    $ZPU1       = $data->ZPU1;
    $ZPU2       = $data->ZPU2;
    $reportId   = $data->reportId;
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO 
                            rows(platform,container1,container2,
                                ZPU1,ZPU2,reportId) 
                    VALUES('" . $platform . "','" . $container1 . "','" . 
                            $container2 . "','" . $ZPU1 . "','" . $ZPU2 . 
                            "','" . $reportId . "')");
    echo "Insert successfully";
}

exit;
```

in config file there is just connection to mysql database :

config.php

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$user = "root"; /* User */
$password = "password"; /* Password */
$dbname = "dbname"; /* Database name */

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confused about how POST requests and HTTP bodies work. Apologies if this is actually just a mistake in your question.

An HTTP request can include several key parts:

- The request method - GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc
- The URL requested
- Headers
- A "body", containing additional data

If you submit a plain HTML form from a website, it will either be turned into a GET request, with the parameters encoded into the URL, or a POST request, with the parameters encoded into the request body. That's why PHP has arrays called `$_GET` and `$_POST`, for retrieving the form details in the two cases - but they don't actually correspond to the HTTP methods, just the way the data is encoded.

`php://input` represents the request body, regardless of what HTTP method was used.

So, finally, to your example request: you have specified a URL, with some parameters encoded in it; PHP will decode those into $_GET; you have specified an HTTP method of POST; but you haven't sent anything in the request body, so php://input will be empty.

Comment: I guess you right and I don't fully understand htttp requests, I had the task to send values from vue (axios) to api written on php and first way to do it I found was json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")) and first problem was in json_decode, then I understood that file_get_contents("php://input") returns string. But the actual problem was in my requests because, I thought that params of Get request is the same as body of post request.